# Simulating an Electric Car Battery in LTSpice

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, ltspice, simulation, modeling

I am sorry if this is a general question:

Does anyone know who to simulate an Electric Vehicle Battery (EVB) in LTSpice (or other free downloadable software)? Are there models I can download online? Where can I find them?

Here is why I "need" such EVB models. My original goal is to recreate/redesign an electric scooter battery for a senior project, but due to COVID-19 I might not get Lab access and so I have to prepare to do things online. A brief description is as follows: solar panels convert solar energy into DC electric current, which passes through a DC to AC converter to make a AC current. This AC current flows through an iron rod transformer and delivers charge onto the electric battery

Also any ideas/suggestions on how to get started on implementation?

Comment: Lots of ltSpice battery models in the groups.io newsgroup files. Batteries are modeled as capacitors in spice.

Comment: Unless you need to study the behaviour of the battery, an equivalent source or a capacitor with series/parallel (parasitic) resistances will do just fine (as mentioned by @user69795 ).

Comment: A battery is charged with a DC battery charger circuit, not with AC. Maybe the transformer AC output is rectified and filtered into DC that feeds a charger circuit.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking too for a model yesterday. After a much search i found that model. Copy the text about leadacid and save it in a text file to your ltspice/lib/sub with name leadacid.sub. Keep in mind that the model has 4 pins, the +, - and rate, soc for making plots.

```
*********************************************************************************
*      LEADACID.CIR - PSpice Lead Acid battery discharge simulator
* Optimized for 6 and 12 volt Lead-Acid Batteries with capacities from
*         1.3 to 10 Amp-Hours. Discharge rates to 1 hour rate
*
*              By: S.C.Hageman  1/9/93   Version: 3/18/93
*
*********************************************************************************

.SUBCKT LEADACID

; ----- Nodes -----
+ +OUTPUT -OUTPUT SOC RATE
;    ^       ^     ^   ^
;    |       |     |   |
;    |       |     |   +---------- Instantaneous discharge rate, 1V=C, 10V=10C
;    |       |     |               refered to 20 hour rate
;    |       |     +-------------- State of charge output node, 1V=100%, 0V=0%
;    +-------+-------------------- +/- Cell connections (Floating)
;
; ----- Parameters -----
+  PARAMS: CAPACITY=1.3 RESISTANCE=0.06 CELLS=3 INITSOC=1
;              ^           ^           ^
;              |           |           |
;              |           |           +--- Number of cells in battery
;              |           |                3 for 6V, 6 for 12V
;              |           +--- Total battery resistance in ohms
;              +--- Battery capacity in Amp-Hours, 1=1A-Hr, 0.5=0.5A-Hr
;                   measured at 20 Hour rate

*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

* * DISCHARGE RATE CALCULATION * *
E_Rate          RATE    0       VALUE = {I(V_Sense)/CAPACITY}
R1              RATE    60      60                      ;R2, C1 = 60 SECOND DELAY
C1              60      0       1 IC=0

* * DISCHARGE AND STATE OF CHARGE * *
G_Discharge     SOC     0       VALUE = {I(V_Sense)}    ;Discharge Current

* * LOST CAPACITY DURING FAST DISCHARGE DELAYED BY R2-C1 * *
E_Lost_Rate     50      SOC     TABLE {V(60)} =
+ (0.05,0.0) (0.089,0.11) (0.16,0.20) (0.62,0.39) (0.8,0.47) (1.6,0.44)

* * AMP-HOUR CAPACITY OF BATTERY * *
C_CellCapacity  50      0       {3600 * CAPACITY * 1.15} IC={INITSOC}
R2              50      0       1G

* * CELL RESISTANCE * *
R_Cell          10      20      {RESISTANCE}

* * BATTERY OUTPUT VOLTAGE * *                              2.171
E_Battery       +OUTPUT 10      VALUE = {V(Cell_V) * CELLS} IC=2.06

* * CELL OUTPUT CURRENT SENSE * *
V_Sense         -OUTPUT 20      0

* * SINGLE LEAD ACID CELL OUTPUT VOLTAGE VS STATE OF CHARGE * *
E_Invert        Invert  0       TABLE {V(SOC)} = (0,1) (1,0)
R3              Invert  0       1G

R4              Cell_V  0       1G
E_Cell          Cell_V  0       TABLE {V(Invert)} =
+ (0.000E+00  2.171E+00) (5.222E-04  2.149E+00) (1.828E-03  2.128E+00)
+ (1.263E-01  2.101E+00) (4.908E-01  2.001E+00) (6.385E-01  1.949E+00)
+ (7.459E-01  1.900E+00) (7.834E-01  1.875E+00) (8.117E-01  1.850E+00)
+ (8.313E-01  1.826E+00) (8.436E-01  1.801E+00) (8.517E-01  1.773E+00)
+ (8.556E-01  1.750E+00) (8.591E-01  1.724E+00) (8.616E-01  1.702E+00)
+ (8.646E-01  1.676E+00) (8.677E-01  1.648E+00) (8.707E-01  1.623E+00)
+ (8.732E-01  1.600E+00) (8.850E-01  1.499E+00) (8.965E-01  1.401E+00)
+ (9.000E-01  1.333E+00) (1.000E+00  0.000E+00)

.ENDS
```

Then make a symbol using the following text and save it in sym folder with name leadacid.asy.

```
Version 4
SymbolType CELL
LINE Normal -32 36 32 36
LINE Normal -32 60 32 60
LINE Normal 0 96 0 76
LINE Normal 0 16 0 36
LINE Normal -20 24 -12 24
LINE Normal -16 20 -16 28
RECTANGLE Normal -16 44 16 52
RECTANGLE Normal -16 68 16 76
WINDOW 0 52 -7 Left 0
WINDOW 3 24 104 Left 0
SYMATTR Value LEADACID
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR Description Lead Acid Battery, either DC, AC, PULSE, SINE, PWL, EXP, or SFFM
SYMATTR ModelFile leadacid.sub
SYMATTR SpiceModel leadacid
SYMATTR SpiceLine CAPACITY=1.3 RESISTANCE=0.06 CELLS=3 INITSOC=1
PIN 0 16 NONE 0
PINATTR PinName +OUTPUT
PINATTR SpiceOrder 1
PIN 0 96 NONE 0
PINATTR PinName -OUTPUT
PINATTR SpiceOrder 2
PIN 32 16 NONE 8
PINATTR PinName SOC
PINATTR SpiceOrder 3
PIN 32 80 NONE 8
PINATTR PinName RATE
PINATTR SpiceOrder 4
```

Read the explanation here about the model: https://web.archive.org/web/20190825095830/http://www.spectrum-soft.com/news/spring2007/battery.shtm (That's a Wayback Machine link, as the original site is now offline). In a hurry, right click the symbol and give the Capacity in Ah, Internal resistance, numbers of cells and the SOC (0 = empty, 1 = full, or between 0 and 1 for different SOC levels) from which it starts discharging.

I am new to these things and if someone understands better, please explain more.